# Python Script to pull data from Blockchain JSON

Tags: python, blockchain

I am trying to write a python script that will take a bitcoin address and show how many transactions have processed against that address. I can pull the JSON data down and print it to the screen but I can not figure out how to actually make it so that I go into that data and pull out "n_tx" potion. Here is what I have so far, basic but it shows I am pulling the right data.

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('http://blockchain.info/rawaddr/1MtKaahhBAwc1Bs9JLgh2tTAmvHL4kauRb')

print r.json()
```

I have read several tutorials and tried lots of different ideas and I am sure it is a simple fix my brain just can't grasp it today.

Ultimately I would like to end up with the following on my screen: 
1MtKaahhBAwc1Bs9JLgh2tTAmvHL4kauRb has 0 transactions

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ??

```
print r.json()['address'],' has ', r.json()['n_tx'], 'transactions'
```

Comment: Exactly like that ! Thank you.